# Javascript, looping through an array and the arguments "object"

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments, for-in-loop

I can't get my head around this, i'm using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to loop through an array and filter out all the integers passed as arguments ,i'm not limited in the number of arguments.

But i'm stuck here when it's about to get back to the function the value of the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object, at least more that once.

In my code below, obviously it's not fully working because i'm doing a `return` within the `for…in` loop, this is where i don't get how I can get the this second loop without having `i` re-initialised to `0`…

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  var args = arguments.length;
  var arg0 = arguments[0];
  var Nargs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  var newArr = [];
  
  
    newArr = arg0.filter(filtre);
    
    /*Only the first argument is 
    filtered out,here it's the value "2",
    but should filter out [2,3].
    The expected result is [1,1]*/
    console.log(newArr);
    return newArr;    
  
     function filtre(e){
 
         for (var i in Nargs){

           return e !== Nargs[i];
         } 
     }
}


destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2,3);
```

Hope this is clear enough,

Thanks for any input !

Matth.

Comment: filter must return a Boolean indicating weather the value needs to be filtered or not

Comment: So `destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2,3);` should return `[1, 1]`?

Comment: @Gerrit0 yes exactly! Adding this to the question for better clarity.

Comment: @CodeBean, ok, but how do you check each arguments separately for the same table ?

Comment: [Don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi, from what JS is telling me here `Nargs` is an object not an array.
`console.log(typeof Nargs); `
as well as the [mdn doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Comment: @MatthieuDucorps `Nargs` is an `Array` as it was created by `slice`, but even `arguments` is an arrary-like object that should be iterated not enumerated. And yes, they're all objects, so `typeof` won't help you distinguishing them.

Comment: `console.log(typeof [])` also logs object. Nargs is an array since you used `Array.prototype.slice.call` on it.

Comment: ok, now i'm confused, it 's reported as an object, but has to be treated as an array :D.
I found Javascript a bit dirty sometimes :(

Comment: Javascript can be confusing, in this case you might find [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your return statement in your filtre function is always executed on the first run, it's only returning the whether the first number in Nargs is equal to the current item. Instead, you can use indexOf for full browser support (which returns the index of the item in an array, or "-1" if it's not in an array) instead of a loop (or includes, or a loop, etc. as shown further below):

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  var args = arguments.length;
  var arg0 = arguments[0];
  var Nargs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  var newArr = [];
  
  function filtre(e){
    return Nargs.indexOf(e) === -1;
  }
  
  newArr = arg0.filter(filtre);
  console.log(newArr);
  return newArr;
}
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2,3);
```

If you don't need Internet Explorer support, you could use `Array.includes`:

```
  function filtre(e){
    return !Nargs.includes(e);
  }
```

And finally, if you *really* wanted to use a loop, you would only want to filter an item (return false) once it's found otherwise allow it (return true):

```
 function filtre(e){
   for (var i = 0, l = Nargs.length; i < l; i++) {
     if (e === Nargs[i])
       return false;
   } 
   return true;
 }
```

Comment: Or even better: `Nargs.includes(e)`.

Comment: @Gerrit0 I don't like suggesting methods that won't work in all widely used browsers but, yes, if OP didn't care about it working in IE then he/she could use `Array.include`

Comment: ok now i have to read again the doc of indexOf cause I don't get it :D

Comment: @MatthieuDucorps I added some more to the answer. `indexOf`returns the index of the item in the array, or `-1` if it's not in the array at all. So, if `Nargs.indexOf(e)` is equal to -1, then it's not in the array and the filtre function returns true to keep it. I've also included more code showing `Array.include` that Gerrit0 suggests and if you *really* wanted to do it in a loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! @rgthree will go through all those solutions to get it properly.

Answer (score 1):

While rgthree provided a solution very similar to what you already had, I wanted to provide a solution that takes advantage of newer ES6 features for modern browsers. If you run this through Babel, it will result in essentially the same code as in that solution, though it will still require a shim for the `includes` call.

```
function destroyer(source, ...args) {
    return source.filter(el => !args.includes(el));
}
```

Explanation:

`...args` uses the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to get all but the first argument into an array named `args`.

We can directly return the filtered array, assuming you don't need to log it and that was just for debugging.

`el => !args.includes(el)` is an anonymous [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Since no braces are used, it will automatically return the result of the expression.

Since `args` is an array, we can directly use [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the current element is in the arguments to be removed. If it exists, we want to remove it and thus invert the return with `!`. An alternative could be the following: `el => args.includes(el) == false`.

Comment: Thx ! I really like how concise is it ! very nice !